# How to force a registered "ambient" object to be resolved?

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container

By "ambient object," I mean one that is always present doing something in the background, but that nobody else knows about. For example, an object that hooks itself up to events on a variety of other objects and logs messages when they fire.

The problem is: since nobody except the Unity builder knows this object exists, nobody resolves it, and it never gets created. Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

I could create a dummy class like so:

```
public class AmbientObject
{
   public object TheObject { get; set; }
}
```

create factory methods that return the ambients inside `AmbientObject` wrappers for each case, register them all with Unity, and then have the composition root do a `container.ResolveAll<AmbientObject>()` (and ignore the return value) simply to ensure they're all created, but that's not exactly elegant.

Comment: Which platform are you using? MVC, Console WPF etc? Can you use OWIN?

Comment: @smoksnes It's WPF

Comment: When do you want it to be created? When other objects are resolved, or during startup?

Comment: @smoksnes At the application's entry point I make a single call to `container.Resolve<MainPresenter>()` which, due to the structure of the dependency tree, has the effect of resolving every single object whose construction is managed by the container (except for these ambients!). So I could just resolve them here manually, or give `MainPresenter` dependencies on all the ambients even though it doesn't actually do anything with them, etc., but I was wondering if the container might have a baked-in solution.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds that you want Unity to automatically resolve your instance in the background.

There's probably a lot of ways of doing it, but I can think of two:

**1.** Do it when creating your container with Lazy.

```
public static class IocContainer
{

    private IMyAmbient _ambient;
    private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> Container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // Do your registration.
        container.RegisterType<IMyAmbient, Ambient>();
        _ambient = container.Resolve<IMyAmbient>();
        _ambient.DoStuff();
        return container;
    });

    public static IUnityContainer Instance
    {
        get { return Container.Value; }
    }
}
```

**2.** Register a [UnityContainerExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainerextension.aspx).

```
public static class IocContainer
{
    private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> Container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer()
            .AddNewExtension<AmbientCreation>();
        container.RegisterType<IMyAmbient, Ambient>();
        return container;
    });

    public static IUnityContainer Instance
    {
        get { return Container.Value; }
    }
}

public class AmbientCreation: UnityContainerExtension
{

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // Using PreCreation, but you may want another one?
        Context.Strategies.AddNew<AmbientCreationStrategy>(UnityBuildStage.PreCreation); 
    }
}

public class AmbientCreationStrategy: BuilderStrategy
{

    private IUnityContainer GetUnityFromBuildContext(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        var lifetime = context.Policies.Get<ILifetimePolicy>(NamedTypeBuildKey.Make<IUnityContainer>());
        return lifetime.GetValue() as IUnityContainer;
    }

    public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        // Runs at every resolve. Now you can decide when to create your ambient object.
    }
}
```

I'm using the later to create log-objects based on stack. Maybe it can get you in the right direction? The downside with both options is that there's no magic going on at all. It just moves the logic to another part of the application. And one may argue that BuildStrategies aren't supposed to be used for this.

More info:
http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/unity-part-10-custom-build-strategies